# Java: How do I draw my rectangle in my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to draw a rectangle in my JFrame but when I run it it just comes up blank. I have tried a few other ways to draw it, but they all come up the same. Keep in mind I'm pretty new, so I'm sorry if there are any obvious mistakes :P.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

JFrame jf1;

public Main() {

    jf1 = new JFrame("Draw");
    jf1.setVisible(true);
    jf1.setSize(900, 700);
    jf1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    jf1.setLocation(dim.width/2-jf1.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-jf1.getSize().height/2);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.fillRect(0, 60, 100, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

}   

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main shoe = new Main();

    }   
}
```

Comment: Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class has a paint method but it's meaningless since the class extends no GUI component and the method is not a true painting method override. Rather than guess at this stuff, read the graphics tutorials:

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics

Then create a class that extends JPanel and draw in its paintComponent method as the tutorials will show you. Place your JPanel in a JFrame and you should be good.

Also -- remember to append `@Override` before any method that you *think* should override a super class's method. If you had done this, the compiler would have complained that your paint method is not in fact overriding anything. Also, don't forget to call the super's paintComponent method as well explained in the first tutorial.